# Queries ran against AWS Oracle RDS DB timing out

Tags: c#, oracle, amazon-web-services

I have some issues with some functions in my application. To be more precise, with my RegisterPuchase function. To be more precise on my Oracle database hosted on AWS.

My application allows an end-user insert(register) and alter(update) a puchase, given that puchase is not yet paid. When inserting the puchase, no problem arises, everyting works as intended.

However, when the user modify the puchase it will run till the subfunction where the itens are inserted to the database, where it will keep running endless, or until "killed". Until then, any attempt to update a puchase afterwards will stop at the UpdatePuchase function. This cause the end-user application to return a timeout error.

For examplification, here is the logic of the webservice implemented on the AWS.

```
private string RegisterPuchase(Puchase puc)
{
    int reterror = 0; // Works only as error identifier
    decimal ValidatePuchaseValue = 0;
    int PuchaseID = 0;
    try
    {
        string NewPuchaseID = "";
        BeginTransaction();
        if (puc.Ped_temp == 0) //New Puchase, This one presents no issue
        {
            reterror = -10;
            NewPuchaseID = InsertPuchase(puc);
            if (Int32.TryParse(NewPuchaseID, out PuchaseID) && Convert.ToInt32(PuchaseID) > 0)
            {
                reterror = -20;
                ValidatePuchaseValue = InsertItens(puc.LsItens, PuchaseID);
                Commit();
                if(ValidatePuchaseValue != puc.Totalprod)
                    //Send Error: Values on Customer end and Server does not match
            }
            else
            {
                reterror--;
                RollBack(); // Call DB RollBack
                return reterror.ToString();
            }
        }
        else //Modify Puchase, presents problem at InsertItens
        {
            reterror = -50;
            NewPuchaseID = UpdatePuchase(puc);
            if (Int32.TryParse(NewPuchaseID.Split('*')[0], out PuchaseID) && Convert.ToInt32(PuchaseID) > 0)
            {
                reterror--;
                RemoveItemsPuchase(PuchaseID); // reterrorr = -51
                //Commit(); // If uncommented along with the BeginTransaction the function works
                reterror--;
                //BeginTransaction();// TEST TEST TEST
                ValidatePuchaseValue = InsertItens(puc.LsItens, PuchaseID);// SQL stuck on ExecuteNonQuery() of the first item
                Commit();
                if (ValidatePuchaseValue != puc.Totalprod)
                    //Send Error: Values on Customer end and Server does not match
            }
            else
            {
                reterror = -60;
                RollBack(); // Call DB RollBack
                return reterror.ToString();
            }
        }
        // Send a Puchase Confirmation Email
        return NewPuchaseID;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        RollBack();// Call DB RollBack
        //Register log
        return reterror.ToString();
    }
}


private string InsertPuchase(Puchase puc)
{
    string sql = @"INSERT INTO PUCHASE (ID, SellerID, CustomerID, Status, Altered) 
                    VALUES (:ID, :SellerID, :CustomerID, 0, 0) ";
                    
    Com.Parameters.Clear();
    Com.Parameters.Add("ID", puc.ID);
    Com.Parameters.Add("SellerID", puc.Seller);
    Com.Parameters.Add("CustomerID", puc.Customer);
    return ExecuteSQL(sql);
}

private string UpdatePuchase(Puchase puc)
{
    string sql = @"UPDATE PUCHASE SET SellerID = :SellerID, CustomerID = :CustomerID, Altered = 1
                    WHERE ID = :ID";
                    
    Com.Parameters.Clear();
    Com.Parameters.Add("SellerID", puc.Seller);
    Com.Parameters.Add("CustomerID", puc.Customer);
    Com.Parameters.Add("ID", puc.ID);
    return ExecuteSQL(sql);
}


public decimal InsertItems(List<CLSItems> items, int pucID)
{
    string sql = @"INSERT INTO items(ID, Amount, Puc_ID) 
            values (:ID, :Amount, :PucID)";
            
    decimal total = 0;
    int i = 1;
    foreach (CLSItems it in items)
    {
        decimal PriceItem = GetProductPrice(it.ID); //Get the price of the product

        Com.Parameters.Clear(); 
        Com.Parameters.Add("ID", items.ID);
        Com.Parameters.Add("Amount", items.Amount);
        Com.Parameters.Add("PucID", pucID);
        total += (PriceItem * it.It_qtde);
        ExecuteSQL(sql);
    }
    return total;
}

public void RemoveItemsPuchase(int PucID)
{
    sql = @"delete from items where Puc_ID=:PucID";
    Com.Parameters.Clear();
    Com.Parameters.Add("PucID", PucID);
    ExecuteSQL(sql);
}


public int ExecuteSQL(string sSQL)
{
    try
    {
        int ret = 0;
        Com.CommandText = sSQL;
        ret = Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code, if I execute the commented commit, no problem arises. However, this is not a good option, as it may break the application should any problem happen middleway.

I do not know how to fix this.

Notes:

- This webservice works properly on my local server. By local I mean a Server that is located in the building, not my computer.
- Aside the connection parameters, the code has no difference between local web service and the remote one.
- The end-user application is sending and receiving response properly, as I can update all the application info from the web service (Items, Customers, Sellers, etc.) both on internal and external network.
- Sending the queries separately works, so the problem does not seems to be the queries themselves.
- Local Oracle version: 11.2.0.2.0
- Remote Oracle version: 19.0.0.0.0

Edit:

- Connection function: new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(@"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;User ID=USER;Password=PASSW");
- The code is creating two sessions on Oracle DB, one inactive and one active that waits the inactive to complete. Killing the inactive usually allows the active to complete.
- Removing the RemoveItemsPuchase function allows the transaction run with no issues. It also applies if we remove the InsertItens instead of RemoveItemsPuchase.

Comment: The command has a default timeout of 30 seconds.  This time can be extended.  What driver are you using to connect to Oracle.  If you are not using an Oracle Driver you may want to switch to Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by driver. In C# code I use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client reference. To test the queries separately, I used the Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: The driver is in the connection string.  See top of following for typical drivers : https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/  Most people with Oracle use a ODBC driver.  ODBC is usually quicker than oledb.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Then, I use the .NET Framework Class Library Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client, that uses the ODP.NET, Managed Driver

Comment: Queries are strings that are inputs to a driver so you do not need (you can) to use a Net Library.  The strings have to be compatible with the driver.  See : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm?force_isolation=true#ADFNS1112

Comment: It may be an stupid question but, If the string is not compatible, shouldn't it return an error of some sort? Also, as stated before, individualy, the queries run with no issues, both using the C# program and the Oracle SQL Developer. Only when I try to run the whole RegisterPuchase to update a puchase that the problem occurs.

Comment: So from what I can understand, the same code works perfectly fine with a local DB but hangs when successfully connecting to an Oracle RDS DB that fails to run the edit-related queries?

Comment: I didn't mean that your code was using wrong query.  It was just meant as a comment that if you switched drivers you may need to modify the queries.  Your issue is time it takes to run query.  Using a different driver may solve issues.  There has been issues for 30 years switching from ODBC to OLEDB.  Industry initially went to OLEDB to make a database driver that was more compatible than ODBC.  Quickly people found out the performance of ODBC was better than OLEDB and many went backwards.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes, that is correct. The first queries that hangs is the INSERT one, after that all UPDATES from the UpdatePuchase hangs. What I find even more strange is that even in this condition, I can insert new puchases from the InsertPuchase.

Comment: @jdweng where do you see oledb???? `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` finds a corresponding ODP driver that must be installed to used that client.

Comment: @jdweng So I misunderstood, I am sorry. As far as I know, the drivers remained the same all this time.

Comment: @Fernando if your code works fast on one server but not another - this is environmental. your network speed, your server type (unix or windows), your data size. If you have 1 million records in your remote server and many indexes, insert will be slower, etc. Then take into account - AWS. AWS EC2 instances could be spun with certain parameters - calls per second, power of the instance machine itself, and many more. There are many limits there. You need to talk to the people who sets this up for you.

Comment: @T.S. : Is ODP OLEDB or ODBC?  OLEDB and ODBC are industry standards for connecting applications to databases.  ODP is a NET compatible driver which  could be OLEDB or ODBC.

Comment: @jdweng `ODP.NET, Managed Driver is 100% managed code .NET Framework provider.`

Comment: @T.S. : But it may run 1000 times slower than ODBC.

Comment: @jdweng You're arguing about something related to code while the problem lies with the DB config - the driver is not the issue here.

Comment: @jdweng this is like - you have a Mercedes but I still can pass you in my KIA. Only the problem, my KIA does not have 120mph safety cage. You will walk out from MB if you overturn 5 times but you will die in KIA. This is exactly what you said suggesting to use some generic provider vs Oracle-developed provider. And besides, Microsoft has it in this framed label - USE vendor-provided data providers. i.e. for MySql use MySql -developed provider, etc

Comment: @T.S. : If you read my comments I always said to use Oracle Drivers and not generic.  From lost of experience the ODBC drivers are the fastest with Oracle.  And from experience Microsoft doesn't have the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days searching, I found the problem.

There is an old process, from the same application, that runs before the RegisterPuchase, where a few others things are validated.

This process always opens a new connection, regardless if there was a open connection or not, and never closes it, that is why there were 2 sessions on my DB. Since this connection is never closed, it stayed on inactive mode, and when the function RegisterPuchase created a new one, the DB waited for the old one to close, which never happens. Probably because both connections were from the same application.

It never crossed my mind that this old function would be the reason of such strange problem, because it does not access the same tables, and because the timeout always started at the InsertItens and at the UpdatePuchase afterwards.

Now, I do not know why removing the RemoveItemsPuchase or InsertItens function or commiting early made it work, nor why it worked on my local server. I suppose that my local server automatically killed inactive sessions, but I am not sure.

So, bottom line: If you opened a connection make sure to close it and verify if there are any open connection before creating a new one for the same function.

Knowing this, I will check my code to see if there is any other place with the same problem.

Thank you everyone for the help.

Note: If this answer/question is not clear enough, name the problem and I will do my best to fix it.

Comment: Your local server in this case worked as it probably didn't have other connections open as you were the only one using it, but in your non-local environments, you will most likely have other connections open. Interesting problem and solution!